# Nativescript Webpack Installation error

Tags: webpack, nativescript

For minimise the app booting speed i installed the plugin nativescript-dev-webpack, but when i run the app on simulator it shows the error

> Cannot find module 'file-system/file-system-access

Iam stuck with this and cannot move forward, any leads will be helpful.
Attaching a screenshot too
[image]
Thanks and Regards
Arun.

Comment: Are you using a plugin that needs `file-system/file-system-access` or is the module used within your application?

Comment: am using file system, but not file-system-access.